# brew install terragrunt: Error: terraform is already installed from hashicorp/tap

Tags: macos, terraform, homebrew, terragrunt

When I try to install terragrunt on macos with brew, I get the following error:

```bash
==> Installing dependencies for terragrunt: terraform
Error: terraform is already installed from hashicorp/tap!
Please `brew uninstall terraform` first."
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have terraform already installed, run the below to just install terragrunt

```
$ brew install --ignore-dependencies terragrunt
```

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you must unlink terraform before installing terragrunt:

```bash
brew unlink terraform && brew install terragrunt && brew link terraform
```